# Wagtail getting all tags of a specific page type using api

Tags: wagtail, django-taggit, wagtail-apiv2

I am trying to find a way to get the tag list of specific page types using **wagtail api**.

```
 class BlogPage(FreeFormPage):
        #...
        tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)
 class WorkPage(FreeFormPage):
        #...
        tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=WorkPageTag, blank=True)
```

On the docs it is clear that there are endpoints for pages, documents and images. But I could not find an information on tags.

1. Do I have to create another specific page type model that collects all the tags and send them via pages endpoint?
2. Or do I have to add a custom endpoint for tag model?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a custom API endpoint at all. Instead, you'd tell Django Rest Framework what to return when it tries to serialize your model fields.

Below is an example of how to use a custom serializer with a ClusterTaggableManager (`tags`)

```
from modelcluster.contrib.taggit import ClusterTaggableManager
from rest_framework.fields import Field
from wagtail.core.models import Page
from wagtail.api import APIField


class CustomTagSerializer(Field):
    """Custom Tag Serializer."""

    def to_representation(self, value):
        """Loop through all the tags and return the name, slug and caption as a Dict."""
        return [
            {
                "name": tag.name,
                "slug": tag.slug,
                "pk": tag.pk
            }
            for tag in value.all()
        ]


class BlogPage(Page):
    """Custom Wagtail Page with Tags."""

    # ... other fields

    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=BlogPageTag, blank=True)

    api_fields = [
        APIField("title"),
        # ... other fields to turn into JSON
        APIField("tags", serializer=CustomTagSerializer()),
    ]
```

You'll use `api_fields = [APIField(), APIField()...]` and a `serializer` that takes a `Field` class. And in the `to_representation()` method you can loop through all the tags and return a list of dicts (I've written a list comprehension in the example above).

If you open your localhost:8000/api/v2/pages/{page_id} you'll see JSON that looks something very similar to this:

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "meta": {
        "...": "...",
    },
    "title": "Blog Page",
    "tags": [
        {
            "name": "Multiple worded tag",
            "slug": "multiple-worded-tag",
            "pk": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "tag1",
            "slug": "tag1",
            "pk": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think, my post can not represent the problem I have. I need a way to reach the tag model of django-taggit(wagtail is using Django taggit)  and get all the tags of a specific page (via the api ). As in 'give me the tags of blog pages'...

Comment: Do you want a specific endpoint _just_ for getting Tags? Because chances are you're already sending a request for the Blog Pages (or the Blog Listing Page), so you can use the method I wrote for this.

You could access the fields and filter by page type with the Wagtail v2 API as well. example: /api/v2/pages/?type=blog.BlogPage&fields=tags. There's more on this in the docs at https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/advanced_topics/api/v2/usage.html#fetching-content